# Projectile - use .projectile instead of .gitignore for excluding file from projectile-find-file

Tags: emacs, projectile

I'm using projectile on emacs for managing project files.  There are some files
which I've put in my `.gitignore` as they contain my local configuration settings

- `dev/resources/local.edn`
- `.dir-locals.el` etc.

The problem with this is when I use `projectile-find-file`, these files are not listed since
they are in `.gitignore` file.  I do not want projectile to get the list of files to ignore from `.gitignore` and instead only rely on `.projectile` for that.

Keeping files out of git repository should not be confused with listing project files using projectile.  They serve different purpose - `.gitignore` for git and `.projectile` to exclude from listing files using `projectile`.

Is there a way to do this ? I couldn't find any variables to tweak.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've found a possible solution - setting indexing method to `native`

```
(setq projectile-indexing-method 'native)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Projectile Documentation](https://docs.projectile.mx/projectile/configuration.html#:%7E:text=Project%20indexing%20method%20Projectile%20has%20three%20modes%20of,obtain%20the%20list%20of%20files%20in%20a%20project.)  you can change `projectile-git-command` variable.

I am using project detection based on git repository with no .projectile file.

For me to show also ignored files, this change works fine:

`(setq projectile-git-command "git ls-files -zco")`

Answer (score -2):

It's possible to use little bit faster 'hybrid' method